Is there any way for R (RStudio) to use the Windows 10 pagefile?
I am processing a large LiDAR dataset in R with the canopyLazR package, and when RStudio marks that it is approaching a RAM consumption of 128 GB (my physical memory), either R crashes or if the function terminates, it fails to allocate a vector size of XXX GB.
Is there any way to force R to use the virtual memory (pagefile) of the operating system? I have a pagefile on both SSD and HDD of 3X my RAM.
